# How to invert deleting files inside a directory without deleteing the specified ones

Tags: rm

Suppose I have these files in a directory.

```
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── __pycache__
├── recognizer.wsgi
├── requirements.txt
├── src
└── upld
```

In which I want to delete all but excluding the `upld` directory.
Is there any quick and better way to do this, I wonder.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -path ./upld -prune -o ! -path . -print
```

This would use `find` to delete everything from the current directory, including subdirectories. However, the path `./upld` is not deleted (note that this must be the full relative path of the thing you want to skip, from the initial search path).

Run this and check the output, then replace `-print` by `-delete`.

---

The safe option, from the parent of the directory in question:

```
mkdir newdir
mv olddir/upld newdir
rm -rf olddir
mv newdir olddir
```

That is, move the `upld` subdirectory out of the way for safe-keeping, then delete the old directory completely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `bash`, there at least to ways. I recommend you play with `ls` or `echo` first and when you are happy with the results you try `rm`.

1 explicit what you want to remove, for example:

```
ls -d [_a-s]*
```

2 explicit what you want to keep, for example:

```
shopt -s extglob # just once per session
ls -d !(upld)
```

You can find more info on bash pattern matching [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).